# how haystack retrieve all indexes with elasticsearch

Tags: search-engine, elasticsearch, django-haystack

Edition:[django-haystack v2.0.0-beta   pyelasticsearch(toastdriven) 0.0.5   elasticsearch0.18.5]
I am trying use haystack with elasticsearch. I have finished steps in [Getting Started with Haystack](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html),and  it works fine. I can create index of `Note` model using `python manage.py rebuild_index`, and retrieve the index in `Note` successfully. Now I have two index folders, one named `haystack` which is created by haystack, the other named `bolg` which is created by `curl -XPUT`. But haystack only can retrieve indexes in folder `haystack`. How to let haystack retrieve indexes in `blog`? How to retrieve all indexes (some of them maybe copy from other machine) using haystack?

Comment: Was the issue ever resolved or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Put a different search_indexes.py in the new app. Haystack will automatically pick the file . When you will run rebuild_index it will index the other app also.